# logic only on href having certain text - jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, href, siebel

I have several a tags on a dynamically generated web page and they are like this

```
<a href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm9_0,s_12,"s_9_1_35_1","1-3ZR4-1743")'  tabindex=997  id='s_9_1_35_1'>Add</a>

<a href='JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm9_0,s_13,"s_9_1_36_1","1-3ZR4-1743")'  tabindex=997  id='s_9_1_36_1'>Cancel</a>
```

several others like mentioned above. I need to execute some logic when link with text 'Add' is clicked. I know one of the way is to attach click event to a tags and then check for text.

```
$('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').click(function(){
if($(this).text() == "Add"){
//do something
}
```

but I am not sure if this is most efficient way to do this.

Can you guys please suggest the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but you have problems with brackets.I tested on jsfiddle

```
$('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').click(function(){
if($(this).text() == "Add"){
//do something
    alert('ok')}
});​
```

Comment: missing bracket was typo error on my part. I know this code works but the question was is this the right way or efficient way to do it???

Comment: Well it depends on what your constrains are. If you are not able to reference to the elements in different way than you need to (select all a where href like '%SWESubmitForm%') will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this.

As you posted in another answer that you wanted to know whether this is 'the right way' - I would say no. The right way would of course be to assign a class to each of these links then use a class selector to bind the click event to them. But I am assuming that you don't have too much control over the html.

That being said I would use filter as I have suggested below. This minimizes the number of events which are bound. If you want to make it even more efficient I would instead make use of `delegate` or `on` and bind to a common parent. This reduces the number of bound click events also.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/Uypuq/

```
$('a[href*="SWESubmitForm"]').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Add") {
        return true;
    }
}).click(function() {
    alert();
    return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If the link id is predictable and as shown in your HTML, you can just use this:

```
$('#s_9_1_35_1').click(function() {
    // put your code here
});
```

If you control the HTML, you can either put an appropriate ID or class on the desired links and just use selectors off those.  That is much more efficient than trying to filter all links based on their text.

Comment: no the id's are generated dynamically... it will have a different id every time the page is loaded

Comment: @user1017268 - can you put a particular class name on the add buttons only?  It's just not very efficient to search the text of links on the page.  And, what it the point of some framework generating an ID that's never the same so nobody can use it in javascript?

Comment: it is not possible to do that. I cannot modify the code being generated. I have to work with the code being generated